# How to delete the timestamp when deploying to local maven repository?

Tags: maven

as the titile mentioned, how to delete the time stamp when I use "mvn deploy"? It always add the time stamp to the jar file no matter what I set the value of "uniqueVersion". I try to set it to "true" and "false", but the result is the same. 
By the way, the value should be false if I don't want the time stamp, right?

Comment: Are you uploading snapshot version to repos.?

Comment: please show your POM

Comment: Are you talking about the timestamp which is created by a repository manager like Nexus within the repository? The uniqueVersion has been deprecated for a long time. maven-deploy-plugin only contains it for compatibilty but it doesn't did something valueable with it...

Comment: Yes @khmarbaise , I'm using Nexus as the private remote repository. Thanks for your information, and do you know how to solve it? As the uniqueVersion has been deprecated, is there anything else to replace it?

Comment: Nexus will always create those timestamp plus an incremental number which can't be deleted. The question is what you like to achieve?

Comment: But I actually found the older version of the snapshot in the Nexus is without timestamp, I don't know how they are deployed as I could not found   who deploy them. The reason I concern about the timestamp is when I retrieve the jars in my ant script (using "artifact:dependencies" tag) on Jenkins, the timestamp will also exists. Is it possible that I can delete the timestamp when I get the jars?